# Intel Graphics issue with Bootcamp

Tags: imac, bootcamp, driver, windows, macos

I have Windows 8.1 x64 on my iMac 2011 with AMD graphics. It works fine, except for when my Mac goes to sleep and I wake it up, I get BSOD with System exception not handled igdkmd64.sys. I looked it up, it's Intel Graphics Driver. Why does this error occur with AMD? And how to fix it? I used Mountain Lion assistant, and installed first Win8 compatible drivers.

Comment: What version of the bootcamp assistant did you use? Some macs don't handle 8.1 very well :/

Comment: I used Mointain Lion one.